# unbound grid for .net

Tags: .net, grid

can i have your opinion ?
I want to develop .net winform application and i want to use fully unbound grid.
Anybody ever use 10Tec iGrid.net and Xceed grid for .net ?
which one is better ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you search the web for some reviews, download the trials (if available) and use the components to discover which is right for your specific requirement. This question in itself is subjective and without the intimate knowledge of your requirement, likely to result is answers that aren't right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add another possibility to your investigation...  I have not used either of those controls but have used Farpoint's [Spread](http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadnet/spreadnet.aspx) control.  It is very easy to use, especially unbound and is very stable.  We've used it on a number of projects and love it.